# How to add an a class to an ArrayList in another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've created a program includes a ***super class*** called **"Appliance"**, from this I have sub classes such as **"ElectricCooker"**. I need to know create an ArrayList that stores all of these Appliances in another class. I'm a little confused on how to accomplish this. This is what I have done so far:

```
   ArrayList<Appliance> applianceList = new ArrayList<>();
    ElectricShower a = new ElectricShower(0,0,0,0);

    public void addAppliance()
    {
         applianceList.add(a);

    }
```

Is this the correct way to implement this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be confusing classes and instances. Did you mean `new ElectricShower()`?

Comment: Ok, what's the question now? Does your code work?

Comment: Yes I have it working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be needing to review the concepts of [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). This should accomplish what you want in Java:

```
public class Appliance {
    // Appliance definition goes in here
}

public class ElectricShower extends Appliance {
    // ElectricShower definition goes in here
}

public class AnotherClass {
    ArrayList<Appliance> appliances = new ArrayList<Appliance>();
    public void addAppliance(Appliance appliance) {
        this.appliances.add(appliance);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
AnotherClass another = new AnotherClass();
ElectricShower shower = new ElectricShower();
another.addAppliance(shower);
```